# Uninstall RabbitVCS

Tags: 15.04, svn, rabbitvcs

Following the tutorial from official site
http://wiki.rabbitvcs.org/wiki/support/uninstall-nautilussvn

I try

```
dpkg –purge rabbitvcs
```

And I got this

```
dpkg: error: need an action option
```

Please help. I use Ubuntu-15.04 x64. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
sudo dpkg --purge rabbitvcs
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get purge rabbitvcs
```

Answer (score 5):

Well `sudo dpkg --purge rabbitvcs` doesn't work for me, i only wanted to remove rabbitvcs from **nautilus**. It was scanning again and again each time when i open initialized repository's folder.

I ran this command first to list all the **rabbitvcs** packages installed.

```
dpkg -l | grep rabbit
```

then ran the following to remove rabbitvcs nautilus package:

```
sudo dpkg --purge rabbitvcs-nautilus3
```

You can uninstall other packages as well:

```
rabbitvcs-cli rabbitvcs-core rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-nautilus3 rabbitvcs-thunar
```

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get purge rabbitvcs*
```

This will remove all the packages that were installed when installation was done using:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs*
```